# SQL, Select group by count, on max number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

we have the following SQL. Group by product_id and count. Limit 6. Query and example output below.

Now, suppose I would want the the `Group by product_id and count. Limit 6.` to be based on the *last 1000 records* in the table? So not the whole table, but only group/count based on the last 1000 records. Can this be done?

I am already using the LIMIT to catch the top 6. But is there a way to LIMIT the number of columns that get counted.grouped to a MAX?

Hope this is clear

thx, Sean

```
SELECT `t`.`product_id` AS `id`, COUNT(*) AS `cnt` 
FROM `sofreport_viewed_product_index` AS `t` WHERE (t.product_id != '24') 
AND (t.store_id = '1') GROUP BY `t`.`product_id` ORDER BY `cnt` DESC LIMIT 6
```

---

```
id  cnt
9   239
440 179
216 169
10  157
494 126
500 118
```

Comment: Do you have an identity column? I.e, HAVING id_col > max(id_col) - 1000

Comment: If you are really only talking about a thousand rows, why not just do a subquery for the the thousand rows? Or for that matter, you could even be pretty lazy and create a view which is simply the `select * ORDER BY insert_date DESC LIMIT 1000` of the base table. I am confused by the "max number of columns" in your title, as it seems like you are asking about max rows, unless I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: How do you define the "last 1000 records"?  Do you mean the last 1000 records that were added--and if so, do you have a field that identifies when the row was added? Or do you mean the highest 1000 counts?  The answer is really dependent on your definition of the "last 1000 records".

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work like that,

```
SELECT `t`.`product_id` AS `id`, COUNT(*) AS `cnt` FROM
`sofreport_viewed_product_index` AS `t` WHERE (t.product_id != '24')
 AND (t.store_id = '1') and t.product_id in
(SELECT id FROM sofreport_viewed_product_index ORDER BY ‘cnt‘ LIMIT 1000 )
GROUP BY `t`.`product_id` ORDER BY `cnt` DESC LIMIT 6
```